# Fastest way for axis-wise matrix multiplication in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, median

I want to multiply the same matrix **axis-wise**, where a matrix A has the shape (n, d):
e.g. (3, 5):

```
A = array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
           [ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13],
           [ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14]])
```

I don't know whether this multiplication or product has a name, because I didn't find anything common. But my goal is, to multiply this matrix, such that all rows are multiplied with all the other rows, and creates a new matrix (`mul`) with the shape (n, n):

[image: formula]

In the end I would like to calculate the median along the third axis `np.median(mul, axis=2)`.

[image: formula]

I implemented this calculation the way below, with a double for-loop, but unfortunately this has a time-complexity of O(n²). Therefore, it takes a really long time to calculate it for bigger matrices.

```
temp_list = []
for i in range(0, matrix.shape[0]):
    row = []
    for j in range(0, matrix.shape[0]):
        mul = matrix[i, :] * matrix[j, :]
        row.append(np.median(mul))
    temp_list.append(row)
return np.asarray(temp_list)
```

#### Is there a way to make this calculation more time efficient?

Comment: you are doing the same multiplication again and again. Can you show this logic if we have 4 rows, are you taking all combinations of rows , 4C2 -> 6?

Comment: Yes sorry. The numbers in the formula were wrong. It should be correct now, and yes as I wrote down, I want to have a combination of all rows with all other rows, creating a symmetrical matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12],
              [ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13],
              [ 2,  5,  8, 11, 14]])

mul = A[None, :, :] * A[:, None, :]

np.median(mul, axis=2)

# array([[36., 42., 48.],
#        [42., 49., 56.],
#        [48., 56., 64.]])
```